# Cant Inspect Compose UI in Landscape Mode using Appium Tool

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, appium, appium-android, appium-inspector

I am trying to write the test suite for the compose UI, my screen follows the sceenOrientation as landscape mode, When I try to hover the screen and inspect a single view whole screen is been seen as selected But when I try with portrait mode I don't seen any issue. I have attached the screenshot of both view. need a solution to inspect each component view in landscape as portrait mode

[image]